# Как по форме отправить данные select и записать в массив? в БД все нормально падает а вот из массива не могу вытащить?

Tags: php, oracle

Пишу на MVC. Не могу записать в массив вид отпусков и вывести ее

```
if (isset($_POST['ID_PERSONholi']))
    {
    $ID_PERSONholi = $_POST['ID_PERSONholi']$DATE_BEGINholi = $_POST['DATE_BEGINholi'];
    $DATE_ENDholi = $_POST['DATE_ENDholi'];
    $CNT_DAYSholi = $_POST['CNT_DAYSholi'];
    $PERIOD_BEGINholi = $_POST['PERIOD_BEGINholi'];
    $PERIOD_ENDholi = $_POST['PERIOD_ENDholi'];
    $ORDER_NUMholi = $_POST['ORDER_NUMholi'];
    $ORDER_DATEholi = $_POST['ORDER_DATEholi'];
    $EMP_IDholi = $_POST['EMP_IDholi'];
    $BRANCH_IDholi = $_POST['BRANCH_IDholi'];
    $DEPARTMENTholi = $_POST['JOB_SPholi'];
    $POSITIONholi = $_POST['JOB_POSITIONholi'];
    $AUTHOR_ID = $_POST['AUTHOR_ID'];
    $today_date = $_POST['today_date'];
    $HOLY_TYPE = $_POST['HOLY_TYPE'];
    $HOLY_KIND = $_POST['HOLY_KIND']; //создаем обьект Employee, в параметры передаем ID
    $employee = new Employee($_POST['ID_PERSONholi']); //функция set_inf_to_DB_Holidays() добавляет данные об отпуске
    $sqlHoli = $employee->set_inf_to_DB_Holidays($ID_PERSONholi, $DATE_BEGINholi, $DATE_ENDholi, $CNT_DAYSholi, $PERIOD_BEGINholi, $PERIOD_ENDholi, $ORDER_NUMholi, $ORDER_DATEholi, $EMP_IDholi, $BRANCH_IDholi, $DEPARTMENTholi, $POSITIONholi, $AUTHOR_ID, $today_date, $HOLY_TYPE, $HOLY_KIND);

    // возвращает массив с отпусками

    $listHolidays = $employee->get_inf_from_DB_holidays(); //выводит таблицу с отпусками
    $listUpdateHolidays = $employee->show_data_table_Holidays($listHolidays);
    echo $listHolidays;
    exit; }
```

views: основной кусок кода:
            $z)                                      { $z['VID'] == 1)   / пустое значение выводит

Comment: VIEWS:                                                                                               foreach($listHolidays as $x => $z){                                                                             
       if($z['VID'] == 1) // в базе поля вид 1 равен если с леч пособием это виды отпусков
        {

Comment: вот [отличный способ](http://phpbeautifier.com/beautify.php) бьютифарить свой код

Comment: $ID_PERSONholi = $_POST['ID_PERSONholi'] вот здесь закрыть строку вроде надо

Comment: Выводите данные последовательно. Зачем ломать голову. Сначала одно значение, второе третье и т.д. Ошибка сама объявится

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['ID_PERSONholi']))
    {` не вижу где закрывается

Comment: закрывается после exit }

Comment: я вывожу с помощью print_r($listHolidays) у меня выводит          Array ( [0] => Array ( [DOC_CONTENT] => [ID] => 3919 [ID_PERSON] => 309 [DATE_BEGIN] => 20.06.2016 [DATE_END] => 04.07.2016 [CNT_DAYS] => 15 [PERIOD_BEGIN] => [PERIOD_END] => [ORDER_NUM] => 189-к-о [ORDER_DATE] => 20.06.2016 [EMP_ID] => 111 )                                                                                                      нету поля VID а мне нужно ее вытащить!

Comment: код что приводите в комментариях добавьте в вопрос и отформатируйте вид. Вам в конце концов нужна помощь.